# one explicit Intent for a list of activities

Tags: android, android-intent, explicit-intent

A implicit intent will present a list of Apps to the user when several apps meets the action. The user then chooses an this app is launched.

However, if you have a list of packagenames (or/and classname) is the same possible for explicit intent? Something like (does not work this way, but this is what I want):

```
Intent i = new Intent().setClassName(ListofPackagenames, ListofClassnames)
startActivity(i);
```

With ListofPackagenames a (Array)List of packagenames and ListofClassnames an (Array)List of classnames.
With startActivity, a dialog should be presented much like when you want to start an implicit intent.

If this is not possible, ofcourse I can make a costum dialog.
Is there then a way, only from the packagename or classname, to get appicon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PackageManager` to get the launch activity and create a chooser intent with `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS.`
Something like:

```
List<String> listofPackageNames=....
List<Intent> intentList=new ArrayList<Intent>();
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
for(String packageName:listofPackageNames){
    intentList.add(pm.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName));
}
Intent[] intents=new Intent[intentList.size()];
intents=intentList.toArray(intents);
Intent chooser=Intent.createChooser(intents[0],"Choose ...");
chooser.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,Arrays.copyOfRange(intents,1,intents.length));
startActivity(chooser);
```